# Saving data from a web form to a local file

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to code (.net) in the autosave functionality without clogging the network. I am trying to capture data from a webpage into a file on the local drive and automate save every 5 mins. Then finally when the user hits "save" the data should be pulled from the local file to update the data base. This should help to auto save without clogging the network.
Any other suggestions are welcome.
regards
SB

Comment: So, what are you actually asking about here?

Comment: **Why** are you doing this? What network problems have you experienced where you've clogged up your network? To be honest, your typical textboxes and textareas won't be of any kind of trouble for your network. What makes you think you have a problem? Even *if* the user's data is large enough to 'clog the network', wouldn't the sum of the user's data be transmitted into your local file anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory HTML5 suggestion! Here we go..

Check out [this post](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/01/12/asp-net-and-html5-local-storage.aspx) of HTML5 local storage and asp.net.